# Specifying default value for template function argument

Tags: c++, templates

Could you explain why the following code doesn't compile? An obvious workaround is to add a 1-argument overload of `Apply`, is there a simpler one?

```
template <typename T>
T Identity(const T& i_val)
  {
  return i_val;
  }

template <typename Val, typename Fn>
Val Apply(const Val& v, Fn fn = Identity<Val>)
  {
  return fn(v);
  }

int main() {
  Apply(42);              // error: no matching function for call to 'Apply(int)'
  Apply(42, Identity<int>); // OK
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: you have no default value for template.

Comment: Note that your `Identity` function always makes a *copy* -- is that intentional?

Comment: @KerrekSB: It is not intentional. Is it relevant to the question?

Comment: @Andrey: No, it's just a comment.

Comment: @KerrekSB: What is a danger if it is making a copy? (probably, it would be a separate question:) )

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: wouldn't RVO be used?

Comment: @Andrey: Apart from the fact that creating completely unnecessary dead code to eat up a user's battery may be considered poor form, you also limit your code dramatically by excluding all non-copyable types.

Comment: lol yes it would be ,but kerrek made much better point than me , what if type if non-copyable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking up the function to call consists of:
1. creating the set of candidates, which includes template argument deduction
2. determining the best overload

If I understand the standard correctly, only actual function arguments (i.e., not the default ones) take part in deducing the template arguments. Therefore from the argument `42`, the only thing the compiler can infer is that `Val` = `int`. The overload does not enter the candidate set and the default argument is never looked at.

Answer (score 10):

Template argument deduction doesn't work that way -- you can't deduce the type of an argument from a defaulted value. In C++11, you can however specify a default template argument:

```
template <typename Val, typename Fn = Val(&)(Val const &)>
Val Apply(const Val& v, Fn fn = Identity<Val>)
{
   return fn(v);
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain your sentence `you can't deduce the type of an argument from a defaulted value` with example in your answer? thanks

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: What I mean is that you can't deduce the type of `fn` from a value that's given as a defaulted function argument. Argument deduction can only be performed on function arguments that were specified at the call site.

Answer (score 0):

Apply is a templated function. You need to do `Apply<MyValueType,MyFuncType>(42);`

You could reasonably expect the compiler to infer `Val` to be `int`, but you can't expect it to infer the type of function, even though you've given a default parameter. As a result, it won't infer that you're trying to call that declaration of the `Apply` function.